# Passing a list of objects between events in a single ASP.NET form from DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, devexpress

So I have a website coded in c#, and when I load a certain form, it loads with it a several records from a database and populates a grid view. One event is a button click for a button marked resend. This method takes all items in the grid that are selected and will resend them. If the selected items don't follow a particular set of rules another form pops up and says that the records must be moved to resend. The user has the option to hit yes and move the records or no and continue on with their business.

I need to pass the list of selected items from the resend click to the yes click on the separate form, the only issue is the popup and the grid are technically the same form. I can load it and all that jazz, but the load event and all of the popup's code is located in the same form.cs as the grid. I haven't been able to make event handlers work. I normally create a custom EventArgs class and store the values in there, but since the two forms are technically the same, I'm not sure how to transfer the information properly. I keep getting a null reference exception when I try to access the list of selected values from my yes click event.

Any suggestions as to what I should do? Properties and variables haven't worked, which leads me to believe they are technically two different forms, I just don't know how to work with them in this context.

If you need code or want anything clarified let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the list of selected items in `Session` cache, like this:

```
protected void buttonResend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Items> listOfSelectedItems = new List<Items>();
    // Put logic here for populating listOfSelectedItems

    // Store listOfSelectedItems in Session cache
    Session["SelectedItems"] = listOfSelectedItems;
}
```

Note: I made up the `Items` class that is stored in `List<T>`; obviously whatever class you have for holding the selected items will work or even just a list of `string`s.

Now in the "other" page, you can retrieve the `listOfSelectedItems` in `Session`, like this:

```
if(Session["SelectedItems"] != null)
{
    List<Items> listOfItems = Session["SelectedItems"] as List<Items>;

    // Put logic here to work with list of selected items
}
```

Comment: Holy balls, I'm dumb. First time with ASP.NET! Thanks you so much!